# Screenshots are not generated when the Test fail for Chrome Browser for android device

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I am new to Mobile Automation testing. I am trying to enhance my web testing framework (for testing browsers on MAC and Windows) to testing the website on Chrome browser for android device and Safari for IOS.
In the same framework I am using web driver and Appium driver depending on the platform which I am giving as a parameter.

Everything works fine if tests are successful. But if the Test Case fail  the method generating Screenshot don't generate screenshot for android and the browser don't close on the device if after the Test Suite have failed. It works fine for IOS.

Kindly help with the issue I am not able to pinpoint the problem.

Screenshot Method:-

````
```public String takeScreenShot(WebDriver driver, String fileWithPath) throws IOException
    {
        File src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        try {
            //String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy"+"@"+"hh"+"_"+"mm");
//              FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"ScreenShots"+File.separator+ System.currentTimeMillis() +"_"+fileWithPath+".png"));
            FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"build"+File.separator+"screenShots"+File.separator+ formater.format(calendar.getTime())+ "_"+fileWithPath+".png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return fileWithPath;
    }```
````

Method using the screenshot method:-

````
```@Override
    public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {

        Logs.error(TAG,"TestCase "+result.getMethod().getMethodName()+" has failed");
        Logs.info(TAG, "Capturing the Screenshot");

        try {
            screenShot.takeScreenShot(driver, result.getMethod().getMethodName());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " failed!"));
        test.get().fail(result.getThrowable());

    }```
````

The console output:-

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'Contact Us')] | //span[contains(text(),'Contactez-nous')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.158)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565386 (45a059dc425e08165f9a10324bd1380cc13ca363),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {appActivity: com.google.android.apps.chr..., appPackage: com.android.chrome, appiumVersion: 1.10.0, automationName: uiautomator2, browserName: Chrome, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appiumVersion: 1.10.0, automationName: uiautomator2, browserName: Chrome, deviceName: emulator-5554, noReset: true, platformName: android}, deviceApiLevel: 28, deviceManufacturer: Google, deviceModel: Android SDK built for x86, deviceName: emulator-5554, deviceScreenDensity: 420, deviceScreenSize: 1080x1920, deviceUDID: emulator-5554, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, noReset: true, pixelRatio: 2.625, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 9, statBarHeight: 63, takesScreenshot: true, viewportRect: {height: 1731, left: 0, top: 63, width: 1080}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//span[contains(text(),'Contact Us')] | //span[contains(text(),'Contactez-nous')]}

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:424)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:152)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:314)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at com.virtualassistance.mobilepagerepository.MobileRogersPage.contactLinkProd(MobileRogersPage.java:18)
    at com.virtualassistance.baseclass.Testsuites.MobileTestSuites.LiveChatButtonMobile.openContactUs(LiveChatButtonMobile.java:433)
    at com.virtualassistance.baseclass.Testsuites.MobileTestSuites.WelcomePageNegativeTestMobile.VA6TC006_MoreThanFiftyWords(WelcomePageNegativeTestMobile.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)

ERROR: TR_ListernerClass: TestCase VA6TC006_MoreThanFiftyWords has failed
INFO: TR_ListernerClass: Capturing the Screenshot
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/element 404 32012 ms - 1128
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (c876268f)] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot'
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/986481328320f68e767f5d88edd99534/screenshot] with body: {}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot - - ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (c876268f)] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[JSONWP Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ESOCKETTIMEDOUT","connect":false}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot'
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/986481328320f68e767f5d88edd99534/screenshot] with body: {}
[debug] [W3C (c876268f)] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
[debug] [W3C (c876268f)]     at doJwpProxy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:547:13)
[debug] [W3C (c876268f)]     at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
[JSONWP Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ESOCKETTIMEDOUT","connect":false}
[debug] [W3C (c876268f)] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
[debug] [W3C (c876268f)]     at doJwpProxy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:547:13)
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot 500 359839 ms - 717
[HTTP] 

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'mobileLIVEs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:142e:1580:bcd1:db32%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {appActivity: com.google.android.apps.chr..., appPackage: com.android.chrome, appiumVersion: 1.10.0, automationName: uiautomator2, browserName: Chrome, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appiumVersion: 1.10.0, automationName: uiautomator2, browserName: Chrome, deviceName: emulator-5554, noReset: true, platformName: android}, deviceApiLevel: 28, deviceManufacturer: Google, deviceModel: Android SDK built for x86, deviceName: emulator-5554, deviceScreenDensity: 420, deviceScreenSize: 1080x1920, deviceUDID: emulator-5554, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, noReset: true, pixelRatio: 2.625, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 9, statBarHeight: 63, takesScreenshot: true, viewportRect: {height: 1731, left: 0, top: 63, width: 1080}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:46)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:294)
    at com.virtualassistance.baseclass.utilities.ScreenShot.takeScreenShot(ScreenShot.java:17)
    at com.virtualassistance.baseclass.utilities.ListernerClass.onTestFailure(ListernerClass.java:65)
    at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:67)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1389)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:636)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)

ERROR: TR_ListernerClass: TestCase VA6TC006_MoreThanFiftyWords has failed
INFO: TR_ListernerClass: Capturing the Screenshot
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (c876268f)] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot'
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/986481328320f68e767f5d88edd99534/screenshot] with body: {}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot - - ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (c876268f)] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[JSONWP Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ESOCKETTIMEDOUT","connect":false}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot'
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/986481328320f68e767f5d88edd99534/screenshot] with body: {}
[debug] [W3C (c876268f)] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
[debug] [W3C (c876268f)]     at doJwpProxy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:547:13)
[debug] [W3C (c876268f)]     at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
[JSONWP Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"code":"ESOCKETTIMEDOUT","connect":false}
[debug] [W3C (c876268f)] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
[debug] [W3C (c876268f)]     at doJwpProxy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:547:13)
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/c876268f-dcc3-40c7-baf7-0a219eb22036/screenshot 500 359851 ms - 717
[HTTP] 
11:20:34.551 [main] INFO  org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Shutting down proxy server gracefully
11:20:34.554 [main] INFO  org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Closing all channels (graceful)
11:20:34.554 [main] DEBUG org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ServerGroup - Proxy server unregistered from ServerGroup. No proxy servers remain registered, so shutting down ServerGroup.
11:20:34.554 [main] INFO  org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ServerGroup - Shutting down server group event loops (graceful)
11:20:36.786 [main] DEBUG org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ServerGroup - Done shutting down server group
11:20:36.787 [main] INFO  org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Done shutting down proxy server
Extent Reports Test Suite is ending!
11:20:36.790 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "index.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
11:20:36.792 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("index_en.ftl"): Not found
11:20:36.794 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("index.ftl"): Found
11:20:36.795 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "index.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/Users/navroop/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5/8db4c7ab2a94cb4656cc6fede1bd9b93886a1c55/extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/index.ftl"
11:20:36.824 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "head.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
11:20:36.825 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("head_en.ftl"): Not found
11:20:36.825 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("head.ftl"): Found
11:20:36.826 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "head.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/Users/navroop/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5/8db4c7ab2a94cb4656cc6fede1bd9b93886a1c55/extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/head.ftl"
11:20:36.828 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "nav.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
11:20:36.828 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("nav_en.ftl"): Not found
11:20:36.829 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("nav.ftl"): Found
11:20:36.829 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "nav.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/Users/navroop/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5/8db4c7ab2a94cb4656cc6fede1bd9b93886a1c55/extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/nav.ftl"
11:20:36.833 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "test-view/test-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
11:20:36.834 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/test-view_en.ftl"): Not found
11:20:36.834 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/test-view.ftl"): Found
11:20:36.834 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "test-view/test-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/Users/navroop/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5/8db4c7ab2a94cb4656cc6fede1bd9b93886a1c55/extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/test-view/test-view.ftl"
11:20:36.846 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "test-view/standard.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
11:20:36.847 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/standard_en.ftl"): Not found
11:20:36.847 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/standard.ftl"): Found
11:20:36.847 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "test-view/standard.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/Users/navroop/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5/8db4c7ab2a94cb4656cc6fede1bd9b93886a1c55/extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/test-view/standard.ftl"
11:20:36.856 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - "test-view/standard.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) cached copy not yet stale; using cached.
11:20:36.857 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "test-view/test-view-charts.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
11:20:36.858 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/test-view-charts_en.ftl"): Not found
11:20:36.858 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/test-view-charts.ftl"): Found
11:20:36.859 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "test-view/test-view-charts.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/Users/navroop/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5/8db4c7ab2a94cb4656cc6fede1bd9b93886a1c55/extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/test-view/test-view-charts.ftl"
11:20:36.868 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "category-view/category-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
11:20:36.868 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("category-view/category-view_en.ftl"): Not found
11:20:36.868 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("category-view/category-view.ftl"): Found
11:20:36.868 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "category-view/category-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/Users/navroop/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5/8db4c7ab2a94cb4656cc6fede1bd9b93886a1c55/extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/category-view/category-view.ftl"
11:20:36.880 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "author-view/author-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
11:20:36.882 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("author-view/author-view_en.ftl"): Not found
11:20:36.882 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("author-view/author-view.ftl"): Found
11:20:36.883 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "author-view/author-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/Users/navroop/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5/8db4c7ab2a94cb4656cc6fede1bd9b93886a1c55/extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/author-view/author-view.ftl"
11:20:36.896 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "exception-view/exception-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
11:20:36.898 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("exception-view/exception-view_en.ftl"): Not found
11:20:36.900 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("exception-view/exception-view.ftl"): Found
11:20:36.900 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "exception-view/exception-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/Users/navroop/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5/8db4c7ab2a94cb4656cc6fede1bd9b93886a1c55/extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/exception-view/exception-view.ftl"
11:20:36.914 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "dashboard-view/dashboard-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
11:20:36.916 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("dashboard-view/dashboard-view_en.ftl"): Not found
11:20:36.916 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("dashboard-view/dashboard-view.ftl"): Found
11:20:36.916 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "dashboard-view/dashboard-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/Users/navroop/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5/8db4c7ab2a94cb4656cc6fede1bd9b93886a1c55/extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/dashboard-view/dashboard-view.ftl"
11:20:36.927 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "logs-view/testrunner-logs-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
11:20:36.927 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("logs-view/testrunner-logs-view_en.ftl"): Not found
11:20:36.928 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("logs-view/testrunner-logs-view.ftl"): Found
11:20:36.928 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "logs-view/testrunner-logs-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/Users/navroop/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5/8db4c7ab2a94cb4656cc6fede1bd9b93886a1c55/extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/logs-view/testrunner-logs-view.ftl"
```